# c# does not choose the function I want it to, based on parameter type(inheritance)

Tags: c#, inheritance, types, parameters

I'm not sure how I can explain this, so I'll just show my example and elaborate.

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var test = new ExampleClass(new Bar());

            Console.WriteLine(test);
        }
    }

    class ExampleClass {
        public Foo _foo;

        public ExampleClass(Bar bar)
        {
            _foo = bar;
        }

        public override String ToString() {
            return print(_foo);
        }

        String print(Bar bar) {
            return bar.Name;
        }

        String print(Foo foo) {
            return foo.ToString();
        }
    }

    class Bar : Foo
    {
        public String Name;
    }

    class Foo
    { }
}
```

Ok so this does not work.

Although I can see the type of `_foo` is `Foo` in the declaration, it can also be `Bar`, since it inherits from `Foo`.

**My question is:**

Why doesn't the compiler see the actual type of `_foo`?

Why is `print(Foo)` always executed, eventhough the type is a derived class of `Foo`?

***Edited***

Edited my example code as it still contained to much of my original code.

Thanks Anthony Pegram for the example.

Comment: Why doesn't it know? Simply because that would be too much to figure out at runtime, and would decrease performance significantly.

Comment: Please show the definition of SyntaxNode.

Comment: As @driis states, you don't define `SyntaxNode`, it could be anything and giving a variable the same name as a keyword, like `base`, is a bad idea.

Comment: you need to make it a virtual method and then override it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: This code is very difficult to read because you're using words like "class" and "base" that already have meanings in C#. Can you provide a *simple*, *easy to read*, *complete* file that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: I have revised my example code to show my problem more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not particulary demonstrate your problem well, because you've introduced a field of type `SyntaxNode` without showing how it relates to your `BaseClass/BaseClassExtension` type hierarchy. But there is still something there that can be answered when given understandable types.

> My question is: Why doesnt the .net runtime see the actual type of originalNode? Why does it always go to print(BaseClass), eventhough the type is BaseClassExtention?

The .NET runtime is not what is determining which overload to use. This is a property of the compiler, which uses information it has about the type of the *variable* (or field, property) in order to determine which overload to use.

A simple demonstration. Say we have

```
class Foo { }
class Bar : Foo { }

void Do(Foo foo)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Foo overload");
}

void Do(Bar bar)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Bar overload");
}
```

And then you have code

```
Foo foo = new Bar();
Do(foo);
```

You have a variable of type `Foo` that happens to refer to an object of type `Bar`. The compiler emits code to invoke the `Foo` overload at compile-time, because that's what it knows, and frankly, that's what you have told it to do. (The fact that we instantiated it to an object of type `Bar` on the preceding line is not particularly relevant. On the next line, just consider that `foo` could have come from *anywhere*, and what we know is that variable `foo` is of type `Foo`.)

If you wish to use the more specific overload at runtime, you might explore double-dispatch mechanisms such as the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). Another approach that I don't particularly recommend is to determine the type at runtime via the `dynamic` keyword (there are generally better alternatives if the problem is well understood, but sometimes it fits).

```
Foo foo = new Bar();
Do((dynamic)foo);
```

The semantics of dynamic at runtime is something you can research in your own time, but this effectively produces the result you seem to desire.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out, but it works as expected if class SyntaxNode derives from class BaseClassExtention - so it's difficult to tell what the problem is from the code you've shown us.

This works as I'd expect:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var test = new myNode();

            Console.WriteLine(test);
        }
    }

    class myNode
    {
        public SyntaxNode originalNode = new SyntaxNode{Name = "SyntaxNode"};

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return print(originalNode); // This calls print(BaseClassExtention Class)
        }

        string print(BaseClassExtention Class) // <= This gets called.
        {
            return Class.Name;
        }

        string print(BaseClass b)
        {
            return b.ToString();
        }
    }

    class BaseClass
    {}

    class BaseClassExtention : BaseClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class SyntaxNode: BaseClassExtention
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you expected that `print` will be selected based on run-time type of the `originalNode`. C# is picking functions to  call at compile time - `print` are not virtual methods so call must be resolved at compile time.

So you have

```
 public SyntaxNode originalNode;
 string print(BaseClassExtention Class)...
 string print(BaseClass base)...
```

At compile time one of 2 print functions will be selected (based on if `SyntaxNode` is `BaseClass` or `BaseClassExtension`). If `SyntaxNode` derives from `BaseClassExtension` than `string print(BaseClassExtention Class)` version is used (as it more specific than `BaseClass` one even both could be used), otherwise the other version.

If you want behavior to be different based on run-time type of `originalNode` you need to either call some virtual method of `originalNode` as part of `print` or manually check type and do something inside of your `print` method.